# With a complex variable, how can I reference from one property to another?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Hi have the following complex variable in the template:

```
"rabbitVm": {
      "size": "Standard_A2_v2",
      "nicName": "[concat(variables('resourcePrefix'),'nicrabbit',parameters('tenantId'))]",
      "machineName": "[concat('vmrabbit',parameters('tenantId'))]"
    },
```

I want to add another property called "resourceName" which should be the *machineName* property with a prefix. I tried adding another property to the rabbitVM object, like this:

```
"resourceName": "[concat(variables('resourcePrefix'), variables('rabbitVm').machineName)]"
```

But I get an error that I can't reference the variable from within the variable.

What is the proper way to reference an another property in the same variable?

Comment: I assume you don't just want to concat the prefix, 'vmrabbit', and the tenantId? :)

Comment: I prefer reuse existing variables, as I might want to change my naming format later on, without changing too many variables.